# ¿Cómo agrego dos series de un archivo json en highcharts?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Tengo el siguiente archivo json:

> {"**temp**":[{"y":"2019-12-26
>   00:00:16","**item1**":"11.00000"},{"y":"2019-12-26
>   00:05:24","item1":"11.60000"},{"y":"2019-12-26
>   21:08:12","item1":"13.10000"}],"**hume**":[{"y":"2019-12-26
>   00:00:16","**item1**":0,"**item2**":0},{"y":"2019-12-26
>   00:05:24","item1":0,"item2":0},{"y":"2019-12-26
>   21:08:12","item1":0,"item2":0}]}

El cual, como pueden ver, entrega datos de dos variables: temp y hume, las cuales a su vez entregan una serie en el caso de temp (item1) y dos series en el caso de hume (item1, item2).

¿Como puedo graficar todas las series usando Highcharts?, especificamente el grafico basic line?.

```
Highcharts.getJSON('url://archivo.json', function (data) {
// Create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {


    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Variables'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Temperatura y Humedad',
        data: data,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }]
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Espero que esto sea que lo necesitas, saludos

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = JSON.parse('{"temp":[{"y":"2019-12-26 00:00:16","item1":"11.00000"},{"y":"2019-12-26 00:05:24","item1":"11.60000"},{"y":"2019-12-26 21:08:12","item1":"13.10000"}],"hume":[{"y":"2019-12-26 00:00:16","item1":0,"item2":0},{"y":"2019-12-26 00:05:24","item1":0,"item2":0},{"y":"2019-12-26 21:08:12","item1":0,"item2":0}]}')
  
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
      rangeSelector: {
          selected: 1
      },

      title: {
          text: 'Variables'
      },
      
      xAxis : {
        categories : data.hume.map(row => row.y)
      },

      series: [
        {
          type: 'line',
          name : 'Humedad',
          data : data.hume.map(row => Number(row.item1))
        },
        {
          type: 'line',
          name : 'Temperatura',
          data : data.temp.map(row => Number(row.item1))
        }
      ]
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  container
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Victor. Primero que todo gracias por responder. Efectivamente resulta, los grafica, pero me queda la otra parte, ¿como puedo hacerlo para que esos datos los tome desde un archivo .json?...

Comment: el archivo json es estatico?

Comment: Podría cambiar según un filtro previo que aplico antes de generar el archivo, entonces debo poder leer directamente el archivo y así después crear un script que lo genere.

Comment: para eso podrías usar un ajax por ejemplo que apunte a un webservice `$.ajax`